# C#,modbuss rs-485 авторизация

Tags: c#

пытаюсь сделать подключение, но авторизоваться в сети не получается

string ip = "192.168.1.178";

```
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 11004);

        ModbusTcpSlave modbusTcpSlave = ModbusTcpSlave.CreateTcp(1, serverSocket);

        modbusTcpSlave.ModbusSlaveRequestReceived += Slave_ModbusSlaveRequestReceived;

        await modbusTcpSlave.ListenAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("ServerStarted");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Порт на маршрутизаторе пробросили?

Comment: @aepot да, т когда запускаю порт открывается

Comment: Ну попробуйте телнетом подключиться к порту, пойдут ли данные в TcpClient, если не работает, надо делать диагностику подключения в первую очередь и только потом искать ошибки в коде.

Comment: @aepot https://ibb.co/gZNJ3rz вот

Comment: @aepot насколько я понял там авторизация аналитика и для авторизации в терминале, нужно последние 9 цифр IMEI и как их отправить?

Comment: Не совсем понятно при чем сдесь rs485, если в вопросе tcp.  Если не изменяет память у  modbus секу рность идет только через tls. Тут похоже вендор чет свое придумал. Скроее всего должны быть доки, где это описано.

Comment: @Vasek дело в том, что телеофис использует протокол авторизации аналитика и в итоге получается то, что если ты не знаешь этот протокол то твой сервер не может зарегестрировать терминал у себя, к сожалению я этот протокол не знаю, а они не говорят :(